# Отображение объектов в админке django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

У меня есть модель `Character` и есть модель `Voice` в модели `Voice` есть поле `character` которое связывает их. Как мне в админке, на странице Character вывести все имеющиеся объекты `Voice`, к примеру у меня есть три объекта `Voice` и я хочу, что бы на странице `Character` я видел список всех объектов `Voice`.

Comment: Используйте inline формы или дополнения, пример решения https://habrahabr.ru/post/158155/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [инлайны](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects):

```
class VoiceAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Voice

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return [f.name for f in self.model._meta.get_fields()]

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

class CharactedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [VoiceAdmin]
```

Comment: Вы видимо немного не поняли чего я хочу добиться, мне нужна не возможность добавлять новые обьекты, а исключительно отображение всех имеющихся.

Comment: Исправил, сделал инлайн нередактируемым.